# Limit dropdown options in selectizeInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a selectizeInput in my shiny app as follows:

```
selectizeInput('foo', 'Select foo:', choices = data, multiple = TRUE)
```

`data` has hundreds of options and I want to limit what appears in the dropdown.  So, for example, if someone starts a typeahead I don't want the dropdown to show any more than the first five matching items in `data`.  The reason I want to limit the items in the dropdown for privacy and confidentiality reasons.

Is there a way of doing this within the `selectizeInput` options or by editing css or js to achieve it?

Thanks!